# Clang and GCC disagree on constructor selection when using braces notation and initializer_list

Tags: c++, c++11

In my Qt5 project, I encountered the following setup:

```
#include <initializer_list>

struct QJsonArray;

struct QJsonValue
{
    /*explicit*/ QJsonValue(QJsonArray const &) {}
};

struct QJsonArray
{
    QJsonArray(QJsonArray const &) {}
    QJsonArray(std::initializer_list<QJsonValue>) {}
};

void f(QJsonArray a = {})
{
    QJsonArray b {a}; // GCC: init-list ; Clang: Copy-Cc
    QJsonArray c (a); // GCC: Copy-Cc   ; Clang: Copy-Cc
}

int main()
{
    f();
}
```

You can see that on the commented lines that GCC and Clang disagree on what constructor should be called.

(You can test this code on [C++ Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/) with latest GCC and Clang with flag `-std=c++11`)

If I uncomment the `explicit`, both compilers select the same constructor (the copy constructor).

Which compiler is right here?

Comment: This is the CWG 1467/2137 mess again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GCC is correct here. For non-aggregates, using braced-init-lists can bypass copy constructors, preferring a matching `initializer_list` constructor. Since `QJsonArray` can be implicitly converted into a `QJsonValue`, and `QJsonArray` has an `initializer_list` constructor that takes `QJsonValue`s, that constructor will be preferred, even over the copy constructor.